# How to check Default Meteor Users list in Meteor

Tags: meteor

How to check the default Meteor Users list in Meteor*

I am using the `{{loginButtons}}` Default Meteor LoginTemplate.

It works successfully but where can I check  Registered Users List.

I'm not familiar with Meteor, so please suggest me how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_users).

> **Meteor.users**
>
> A Meteor.Collection containing user documents.
>
> This collection contains one document per registered user.

To return a cursor to the collection of registered users you can use [collection.find](http://docs.meteor.com/#find):

```
Meteor.users.find()
```

To return an array (since you are asking for a "list") containing all registered users you can use [cursor.fetch](http://docs.meteor.com/#fetch):

```
Meteor.users.find().fetch()
```